# WKWebView ScrollView not detecting all scroll movements

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, wkwebview

I am trying to detect scroll movements inside my WKWebView, such as when a user is scrolling up or down.

The problem is that the scrollViewDidScroll method only fires when the entire page moves, not the content of the page. Basically it only occurs if I try to scroll past the top, or below the bottom, but doesn't fire in the middle of the page.

I am using the code like so to determine when it is scrolling either up or down:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSLog(@"%f",scrollView.contentOffset.y);
}
```

Is this a problem with the WKWebView maybe, or is there another content property I should be using to detect the page content offset?

Comment: Are you using `overflow-y` to have an internally scrolling div?

Comment: Ya I think we were, but we decided to not detect the scrolls after all